The call button doesn't seem to be working, how can I make it work?
class PropertyDetailNavBar extends StatelessWidget {
  const PropertyDetailNavBar({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    final loginBloc = context.read<LoginBloc>();

    return BlocBuilder<PropertyDetailsCubit, PropertyDetailsState>(
      builder: (context, state) {
        if (state is PropertyDetailsLoaded) {
          final agent = state.singlePropertyModel.propertyAgent;

          if (agent == null) {
            return const SizedBox.shrink();
          }

          return Container(
            width: size.width,
            height: 190.0,
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 5.0),
            decoration: const BoxDecoration(
              color: primaryColor,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                topRight: Radius.circular(20.0),
                topLeft: Radius.circular(20.0),
              ),
            ),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                          horizontal: 20.0, vertical: 14.0)
                      .copyWith(top: 4.0),
                  child: Row(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      ClipOval(
                        child: CustomImage(
                          path: RemoteUrls.imageUrl(agent.image),
                          height: size.height * 0.08,
                          width: size.height * 0.08,
                          fit: BoxFit.cover,
                        ),
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(width: 10.0),
                      Expanded(
                        child: Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: [
                            CustomTextStyle(
                              text: agent.name,
                              fontSize: 20.0,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                              color: whiteColor,
                            ),
                            CustomTextStyle(
                              text: agent.designation,
                              fontSize: 14.0,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                              color: whiteColor,
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      const Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                        children: [
                          CustomTextStyle(
                            text: "Contact Us",
                            fontSize: 16.0,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                            color: whiteColor,
                          ),
                          CustomTextStyle(
                            text: '+8801977663736',
                            fontSize: 16.0,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                            color: whiteColor,
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(height: 10.0),
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                  children: [
                    Flexible(
                      child: ContactButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          if (loginBloc.userInfo != null &&
                              loginBloc.userInfo!.accessToken.isNotEmpty) {
                            Navigator.pushNamed(
                                context, RouteNames.sendMessageScreen,
                                arguments: agent.email);
                          } else {
                            Utils.showSnackBarWithLogin(context);
                          }
                        },
                        bgColor: yellowColor,
                        text: 'Message',
                        icon: KImages.messageIcon,
                        iconTextColor: blackColor,
                      ),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(width: 10.0),
                    Flexible(
                      child: ContactButton(
                        onPressed: () async {
                          if (loginBloc.userInfo != null &&
                              loginBloc.userInfo!.accessToken.isNotEmpty) {
                            Uri uri = Uri(scheme: 'tel', path: agent.phone);
                            //print(uri.runtimeType);
                            if (agent.phone.isNotEmpty) {
                              launchUrl(uri);
                            } else {
                              Utils.showSnackBar(
                                  context, 'Phone number is Empty');
                            }
                          } else {
                            Utils.showSnackBarWithLogin(context);
                          }
                        },
                        bgColor: blackColor,
                        text: 'Call',
                        icon: KImages.callIcon,
                        iconTextColor: whiteColor,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          );
        }
        return const SizedBox.shrink();
      },
    );
  }
}


I copied the call code from another dart file where it is working perfectly. But when I put it here it is telling me that the number is empty. It should be pulling data from the agent's profile. When I directly go to their profile and press the call button it works.
When I press the call button it should open the phone app with the agent number on it.
